# Automatically click using onload?

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can I automatically click on an object using `onload()` with HTML.

Here's the button I would like to be automatically clicked:

```
<input type="button" value="{$LANG.checkout} &raquo;" class="checkout" onclick="addtocart();" />
```

What I would like to happen is for the button to be clicked automatically; as soon as a certain `div` is loaded. I know it's possible to do with Javascript, but is there any way to do it without javascript? If javascript is the only way I am more than open to it!

Comment: If you need to do it in the browser: other than hiring someone to click it for you, you would need to use JavaScript.

Comment: How else would you do it?

Comment: How is your 'certain div' loaded?

Comment: The purpose of a button is to be clicked by a user, at that user's discretion. If you want to simply have a function executed when an event happens, eg. a 'certain div' is loaded then you need to attach the function to the onLoad event of that div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a comment says, is not need to 'trigger a click automatically', just add the functionality in a script tag (or even better, in a separate file):

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="{$LANG.checkout} &raquo;" class="checkout" />
```

**JS**

```
<script>

addToCart();

function addToCart(){
  //your code here...
};

</script>
```

Include this tag before the tag `</body>` (where body finish) and it will be execute when all your HTML (DOM) be ready.